# C++: no instance of overloaded function unordered_set

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I cannot figure out why compiler keeps complaining about the fact that I tried to insert a `unique_pointer` of `Employee` into a `unordered_set` of `unique_pointer` of `Employee`. Would you please point out what I missed?

```
// c++ test ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>    
#include<unordered_set>
#include "c++ test ConsoleApplication2.h"//this file only contain one line"#pragma once"

std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<Employee >>  scanned_set;
std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<Employee >> to_scan_set;

int countt;



// Employee info
class Employee {
public:
    int getImportance(vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee >>  employees, int id)
    {
        for (auto it = employees.begin(); it != employees.end(); ++it)
        {
            if ((*it)->id == id)
            {
                countt += (*it)->importance;
                std::unique_ptr<Employee > testPointer(new Employee(1, 2,  vector<int>()));
                scanned_set.insert(testPointer); //error occurs here

                scanned_set.insert(*it);
                if (!(*it)->subordinates.empty())
                {
                    for (auto to_scan_iterator = to_scan_set.begin(); to_scan_iterator != to_scan_set.end(); ++to_scan_iterator) {
                        to_scan_set.insert((*to_scan_iterator));
                    }
                    return  getImportance();
                }

            }
        }
    }


    int getImportance();

    Employee(int id, int importance, vector<int>& subordinates) {
        this->id = id;
        this->importance = importance;
        this->subordinates = subordinates;
    }
    // It's the unique ID of each node.
    // unique id of this employee
    int id;
    // the importance value of this employee
    int importance;
    // the id of direct subordinates
    vector<int> subordinates;
};

inline int Employee::getImportance()
{
    if (to_scan_set.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto it = to_scan_set.begin(); it != to_scan_set.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (scanned_set.find((*it)) == to_scan_set.end())
            {
                countt += (*it)->importance;
                scanned_set.insert(*it);
                if (!(*it)->subordinates.empty())
                {
                    for (auto to_scan_iterator = to_scan_set.begin(); to_scan_iterator != to_scan_set.end(); ++to_scan_iterator)
                    {
                        if (scanned_set.find((*it)) == to_scan_set.end())
                        {
                            to_scan_set.insert((*to_scan_iterator));
                        }
                        return  getImportance();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio shows description at the error line:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::unordered_set<_Kty, _Hasher, _Keyeq, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=std::unique_ptr<<error-type>, std::default_delete<<error-type>>>, _Hasher=std::hash<std::unique_ptr<<error-type>, std::default_delete<<error-type>>>>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<std::unique_ptr<<error-type>, std::default_delete<<error-type>>>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<<error-type>, std::default_delete<<error-type>>>>]" matches the argument list c++ test ConsoleApplication2    c:\Users\guo\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\c++ test ConsoleApplication2\c++ test ConsoleApplication2\c++ test ConsoleApplication2.cpp   29
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, but movable. Use `scanned_set.insert(std::move(testPointer));` as for inserting `*it` that would not work, you probably need shared ownership

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_ptr` has a deleted copy constructor. You can only move the ownership. Here is a code sample illustrating a further suggestion.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<int>> us;
    us.emplace(std::make_unique<int>(5));
    //auto ip = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    //us.insert(ip);
    // above does not compile because copy constructor is deleted
}
```

Using `emplace` here could be better since it constructs the object in-place and in a way reminds you of you to move. I think, it is better to use it if you are working with a container of unique pointers. Of course, if you remember to use `std::move`, you can keep using `insert`, really nothing wrong with it.